# How to load geodata from google sheet (columns) instead

Tags: google-maps, google-geocoder

My current data is hardcoded:

```
   var geoData = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        geoData.addColumn('string', 'City');
        geoData.addColumn('string', 'Name');
        geoData.addColumn('boolean', 'Yes/no');

var geoView = new google.visualization.DataView(geoData);
        geoView.setColumns([0, 1]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

var query = new google.visualization.Query('http://spreadsheets.google.com/...')